# Recovery of precipitated polymer

Tags: synthesis, polymers, purification

I have recently newly synthesized the polymer. Based on its structure I tried to precipitate its concentrated solution in dichloromethane by dropping it into methanol. It seemed to work. The methanol solution was cloudy, some gooey things that sticked to the wall of the flask were observed. Initially I tried to recover the precipitated polymer by filtering through membrane filter applying reduced pressure (Chmlab, MTF/H Grade, PTFE hydrophobic membrane filter, pore size 0.2 μm, diameter 47 mm). The solution is cloudy orange color, and the filtrate was yellow color. The filtration seemed successful, but shortly after the filtration hardly continued. I am assuming that the precipitated polymer blocked all of the pores of the membrane filter. When I stopped the filtration and checked the filter, there was no powder-like thing on the top surface of the filter, but something seemed to be adsorbed on the surface. I have tried larger pore size, 1~2 μm, but the filtrate has cloudy orange color same to the solution, and shortly after its pores were also blocked. In this situation, do I have to try centrifuging? After centrifuging, can I recover the polymer simply by pouring it onto the membrane filter and washing with methanol?

Comment: Centrifuging seems the obvious way to go. I might be inclined to put the centrifuge tube in a vac oven to dry it out after centrifuging in the hope that the dried polymer will be easier to handle.

Comment: @Waylander The polymer is sticked to the bottom of the centrifuge tube... Would change of the precipitant to ethanol or IPA help?

Comment: Can you redissolve the polymer in the tube in a little DCM, remove it to a storage vial and let the solvent evaporate to give you your sample? It may be partially soluble in EtOH or iPrOH.